# Simple Ember.js Input Syntax

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm seeing conflicting within the ember guides on how to go about actions syntax on an `{{input}}` helper. I'm referring to the `key-press` and `key-up` parameters.

[This section](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_actions) shows it without parenthesis as such:

`{{input value=firstName key-press="updateFirstName"}}`

Yet [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/) (with the code snippet titled "app/templates/components/list-filter.hbs"), it does use parenthesis as such:

`{{input value=value key-up=(action 'handleFilterEntry') class="light" placeholder="Filter By City"}}`

---

I'm not sure why the API docs leave out the parenthesis but the example puts them in. Any insight appreciated

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's because it's a builtin event that the action part is implied so there's no need for it; it extraneous in  the second snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the below format `key-up=(action 'handleFilterEntry')` , then `handleFilterEntry` function will be called with the following argument `value`,`jQueryEvent`.

Likewise,

`key-up='handleFilterEntry'` ==> value, jQueryEvent

`keyUp=(action 'handleFilterEntry')` ==> Only jQueryEvent

`keyUp='handleFilterEntry'` ==>  Wont trigger the event - this is wrong. Its like normal event, so you need to provide function not the string.

When [Event-Name](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#toc_event-names) is dasherized, inside input helper you will get first argument the value and then jQuery event. if its not dasherized then its normal thing so you will get jQuery Event arguments alone.

[Sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/86a628b4e21fb6f6366ce636868d442a?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) which demonstrate this behavior.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by: _what you will receive in arguments_. Do you have any examples or links to better understand this.

Comment: Thank you, this is making much more sense. Could you explain anyway in which `keyUp='handleFilterEntry'` might work.

Comment: `{{input` helper is designed such a way that it will respond all the events mentioned in https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#toc_event-names but event name must be dasherized. but for normal input element you dont need to dasherize event names. you can use it like this `<input value={{name}} onkeyup={{action 'nameChanged'}} />`. . In this case`keyUp='handleFilterEntry'` event name `keyUp` is managed by browser not by Ember, so you need to assign function not the string.

Comment: For ember managed events(`key-up`) you can mention string/function, but for normal  DOM events (`keyUp`) you need to assign function always.

Comment: This is making much more sense. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am not able to explain things with clear technical term which is used in guides. I will try to be good at it..As your question concerned there is no need to have `key-up=(action 'handleFilterEntry')` in tutorial just `key-up='handleFilterEntry'` this will work. you can create PR in guides repository by saying that your are confused dont understand the for closure action here.

Comment: By clicking pencil icon on that page (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/) you can edit and create PR.